# Keyboard Viewer crashes when I use keyboard command

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, crash

When I try to invoke the Emoji and Keyboard Viewer via the Keyboard shortcut (<kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd>), the menu bar icon crashes on me and the viewer does not invoke.

I tried removing the preference file `com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` as [suggested in this Apple Forum answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7355031?start=0&tstart=0). After restarting the keyboard viewer icon appears in my menu bar (American Flag). I can select items in the menu. As soon as I invoke the keyboard shortcut however it disappears:

[image: Broken Keyboard Viewer]

Do I have a corrupt preferences file somewhere?

I am running macOS Sierra V 10.12.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I found my startup drive was corrupt and I needed to run Disk Utility. Steps I took:

1. Delete `com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` from `Library/Preferences/` folder.
2. Restart machine.
3. Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to run Disk Utility from Recovery HD.
4. Selected Disk Utility from Recovery HD menu.
5. Ran First Aid on my machine.
6. Once finished, I restarted.

After restart the issue went away.